# Need help Fermat's prime calculations

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need help with how to do my assignment. I'm supposed to generate prime numbers with two different methods: Fermat's Little Theorem and the use of square root. When I've generated 3,000,000 numbers with each method (which has different amounts of prime numbers because Fermat's method isn't 100% correct) I'm supposed to find the accuracy of the Fermat's method by dividing the two lists or variables (where all the numbers got saved) with each other to find the trustworthiness of using the first mother over the square root one.

Here is where my problem comes in. In my assignment, I'm supposed to return the value "True" if the number matches the equation and false if not. Somehow I need to add a list or variable while still returning "True" or "False" to save all the numbers so that, in the end, the program can calculate the percentage. I don't really know how to effectively add this and I'd like some feedback on my code so that I may improve it. I'm kind of stuck atm.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem

What the assignment is based on

My progress (I've only done about 3 months of programming so any constructive feedback is much appreciated).

This is only the Fermats version. The other one looks the same but with a different equation. Just need to get a list or variable which saves all the values who are True:

```
from time import *

start_time = time()


def is_prime(n):
    fermat = int(pow(2, n - 1, n))
    while n > 1:
        if fermat == 1:
            return True
        return False


for x in range(1, 30001):
    print(x, is_prime(x))
print("Total amount of time:", time()-start_time)
```

Comment: What exactly are you asking?

Comment: I need to add a list or variable to save all the calculated prime numbers. Since Fermat's little therorem will generate numbers which aren't prime numbers I figured that you would can get the accuracy of Fermat's method by dividing the second list or numbers with the first one. I  need to keep the return True and False and still add a list which saves all the numbers.

Comment: If this is all you want then why don't you define a list or array to which you add one by one those numbers 'n' for which the condition stated in Fermat's little theorem holds?

Comment: I need to return the value as True or False and if i add a list I'd have to return the list instead which the assignment does not want me to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list comprehension to create a list where the index is the number and the value is the primeness of that index.

(Also noticed I refactored `is_prime` a bit. You don't need the `fermat` variable, and you most definitely don't need the `while` loop).

```
def is_prime(n):
    return int(pow(2, n - 1, n)) == 1:

print([is_prime(n) for n in range(1, 30001)])
# [False, False, True, False, True, False, True, ..... ]
```

The caveat is that Python indexes start at 0. We can fix that by prepending a list with a sentinel value:

```
 print([None] + [is_prime(n) for n in range(1, 30001)])
 # [None, False, False, True, False, True, False, True, ..... ]
```

Another alternative will be to use a dictionary where the key is the number and the value is the primeness, but keep in mind that dictionaries are unordered in Python < 3.7:

```
 print({n: is_prime(n) for n in range(1, 30001)})
 # {1: False, 2: False, 3: True, 4: False, 5: True, 6: False, 7: True, ..... }
```

If you are only interested in a list of (presumably) prime numbers:

```
print([n for n in range(1, 30001) if is_prime(n)])
# [3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, .... ]
```

Comment: Thanks! The first one was really helpfull, althoguh that's not exactly what I was looking for or maybe I missed something. My explanation might have been a bit confusing so I'll try to express it as clear as possible. It's great that I have all the numbers now but what I actually need it to comapare the list of True and False with another list which instead uses the square root version. in the end I need to get a percentage of how accurate the Fermat's method is.

Comment: A follow up question on that then if i may. Would it be more efficient if I saved the values as True and False and then compare the amount of True and False in both lists or somehow make True and False into actuall numbers?

Comment: @LudwigWallin You wrote in your question "Just need to get a list or variable which saves all the values who are True:" which is what I showed in my answer. You can do the same with the numbers from the other function. We won't do all the HW task for you.

Comment: Yeah I understand. Just annyoing when I've been stuck on this little thing for like hours but I think I solved it now. Thanks